# Link From Single Post To Taxonomy Term Archive Page

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

Need to add a link on all single pages for custom post type taxonomy terms which links back to the taxonomy term archive the single page belongs to.

Using this code but it adds links for all tax terms. I only need the one the single page is assigned to.

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'portfolio',
) );

if ( ! is_wp_error( $terms ) && ! empty( $terms ) ) {

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

echo '<a href="' . get_term_link( $term->slug, 'portfolio' ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';

    }
}
```

I added this code in the single-portfolio.php file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a good use for `get_the_term_list()` https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list

Comment: I only want to get the term assigned to the single entry, not the entire list. Example: If in same term, link to the term archive.

Comment: @Dev have you tried this? From the codex page it states "Returns an HTML string of taxonomy terms associated with a post and given taxonomy. Terms are linked to their respective term listing pages."

Comment: Yes i have but i only need one which the single post is related to.

Comment: I know i could also use wp_get_post_terms but that also returns a list of all terms the post is associated with. I only want the 1st one.

Comment: @Dev If you do `$all_terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'portfolio' );` and then use `$all_terms[0]` does that solve the issue?

Comment: Didn't work for me however i'll give you the update for effort. I may be wrong with the implementation at my end.